# Poor signal through USB 2.0 Hub IC

Tags: uart, signal-integrity, usb-hub

I’m using an FE1.1S, using only 2 ports which are connected to a Ublox GPS F9P and another to an STM32.
Connecting it to a computer, the hub and com ports show up just fine and I can connect to them.

I can connect to the STM32 device without any issue. The GPS connects to the STM32 via UART and that works.

I noticed when I connect to the STM32 and separately to the Ublox chip via u-center (their software for interacting with their chip), eventually both software stops receiving data - both COM ports are still showing up in the computer with no signs of issues.

After removing the STM32 from the equation, connecting to the Ublox GPS through u-center, it connects and receives data but also indicates the baud rate is too low. Their software has auto-baud, so it determines the best possible baud rate.

Initially I thought the 500mA 3.3v LDO wasn’t enough, but that is enough for the GPS - the STM32 board runs off the 5v VBUS, and draws little current as is.

Then I think maybe poor impedance- I setup Altium for control impedance for the USB using differential coplanar. It’s a 2 layer , with ground plane pours on bottom and top. Would not ideal impedance for USB2.0 (FS) cause such issues? Keeping in mind the hub and ports never disconnect or show signs of issue.

I also thought STT vs MTT hub, but having issues with just a single circuit (GPS) eliminates this in my opinion.

This particular eval board does have traces for a 3rd and 4th USB devices, but I’ve decided to not use them, so maybe this is causing issues with the FE1.1 chip?

So - what is the main cause of poor baud rates? This is likely the common issue.

GPS circuit [image: fp9 circuit]

Comment: What exact U-blox module are you using? How is it connected to the USB hub? Is VBUS connected? What boot-time configuration are you using? The baud rate is irrelevant on a purely virtual serial connection. And impedance is unlikely to be an issue for full-speed USB.

Comment: F9P. I’m using default config for it. Got it on impedance. I added a picture of the circuit.

Comment: Why is VUSB fed with 3.3V? Does it work with 3.3V instead of 5V?

Comment: @Justme According to the data sheet, it needs to be that way. It's not VBUS, it's the supply for the USB interface.

Comment: The shown excerpt seems ok. Have you checked that all the voltages are ok (GPS module, USB hub etc.)? Did you have a look at the D+/D- signal (both upstream and downstream)? Do they look ok?